# Convertir datarowview en C#

Tags: c#

Buenas noches sigo, pasando mi sistema de Vb a C#, ahora tengo este error en esta conversion, yo en visual bacis lo hacia de esta forma:

```
Dim aoRow As dsmstpsnal.GetDetaPsnal01Row = CType(CType(e.Row, DataRowView).Row, dsmstpsnal.GetDetaPsnal01Row)
```

Y el resultado una vez obtenida la conversión, lo tenia así

```
e.Value = cInt(aoRow.IDCODEMP  )
```

ahora hice lo siguiente en C#

```
dshojasadmision.tblAdmonClienteRow CustRow = (dshojasadmision.tblAdmonClienteRow)e.Row;
    e.Value = CustRow.FechaNacimiento;
```

Me da error de conversion que es el siguiente,

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2147467262   Message=No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo
>   'System.Data.DataRowView' al tipo 'tblAdmonClienteRow'.

Cómo es el código en `C#` si existe?

Comment: Tienes que hacerlo de forma manual me temo, puedes crear un método de extension. De todas maneras, `CustRow` tiene las mismas columnas y con el mismo nombre que `e.Row`?

Answer (score 0):

Al convertir el código, pasastes por alto una etapa.

Con tu código en VB.NET:

```
Dim aoRow As dsmstpsnal.GetDetaPsnal01Row = CType(CType(e.Row, DataRowView).Row, dsmstpsnal.GetDetaPsnal01Row)
```

...las etapas que sigues son:

1. Convertir `e.Row` a `DataRowView`.
2. Leer la propiedad `Row` del `DataRowView`, lo que te devuelve un `DataRow`.
3. Convertir el `DataRow` a `dsmstpsnal.GetDetaPsnal01Row`.

Pero con tu código C#:

```
dshojasadmision.tblAdmonClienteRow CustRow = (dshojasadmision.tblAdmonClienteRow)e.Row;
```

... estás tratando de pasar directamente de un `DataRowView` a tu clase `dshojasadmision.tblAdmonClienteRow`. Te olvidastes la etapa intermediaria de extraer el `DataRow` usando la propiedad `Row` del `DataRowView`.

En realidad, el código equivalente a lo que tienes en VB.NET es el siguiente:

```
dshojasadmision.tblAdmonClienteRow CustRow =
    (dshojasadmision.tblAdmonClienteRow)((DataRowView)e.Row).Row;
```